# Protecting Routes in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, authentication, routes, laravel-5.3

I am trying to protect my routes in Laravel 5.3. I am using below codes

```
Route::get('profile', function () {
    // Only authenticated users may enter...
})->middleware('auth');
```

If I try to browse `/profile` in logout situation it redirects me to `/login` route. But I would like to redirect it to `/` route.

How can I do that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On laravel 5.3 it's on Exceptions directory. Go to App\Exceptions\Handler.php and on the bottom change the code:

```
    return redirect()->guest('/');
```

Answer (score 1):

change file **app\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

and edit this line:

```
return redirect('/login');
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. There no such file in Laravel 5.3. You can see this https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/app/Http/Middleware

Comment: Sorry it's RedirectIfAuthenticated then

Answer (score 0):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Please write this function in this file **app\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

Comment: want You make a new middleware??

Comment: No, I did not make any middleware. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'],function (){
Route::Auth();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');});
```

and change app\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```